# “unknown plugin type” for all traefik plugins

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress, traefik-plugins

I am using Traefik as an ingress for my kubernetes and am unable to use any plugin. No logs for plugin getting downloaded. I get error for all plugins like this

```
time="2023-05-18T02:01:32Z" level=error msg="plugin: unknown plugin type: plugin-blockpath" routerName=dev1-api-gateway-dev1-api-gateway-dev-company-com@kubernetes entryPointName=websecure
```

Here is my config.

Static:

```
  values:
    ingressClass:
      enabled: true
      isDefaultClass: true
    ingressRoute:
      dashboard:
        enabled: false
    service:
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    providers:
      kubernetesCRD:
        enabled: true
      kubernetesIngress:
        enabled: true
        publishedService:
          enabled: true
    ports:
      websecure:
        tls:
          enabled: true
      web:
        redirectTo: websecure
    experimental:
      plugins:
        plugin-blockpath:
          moduleName: "github.com/traefik/plugin-blockpath"
          version: "v0.2.1"
```

Dynamic:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: blockpath-health
spec:
  plugin:
    plugin-blockpath:
      Regex:
        - ^/actuator/health(.*)
```

Annotation:

`traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: flux-system-blockpath-health@kubernetescrd`

Answer (score 0):

Block Path is a middleware plugin for [Traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik) which sends an HTTP 403 Forbidden response when the requested HTTP path matches one of the configured [regular expressions](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). Your static configuration file is correct for plugin-blockpath.

Configure plugin using the Dynamic Configuration.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
    name: my-plugin-blockpath
    namespace: my-namespace
spec:
    plugin:
        plugin-blockpath:
            Regex:
                - ^/foo(.*)
```

Can you try changing the regex in dynamic configuration as above. You can refer to this [document](https://plugins.traefik.io/plugins) for plugin installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Srividya. Block Path is a middleware plugin which I am testing right now but other plugins also give me the same error.
I have changed the dynamic configuration as per your recommendation but still the same problem. It is not able to find the plugin from static config.
I have followed the exact process as per the documentation but still the same error.

Comment: Have you  checked your plugins directory? Is it mounted to a storage? If traefik is downloading the plugins it should write the plugins to plugin directory to save the file.

Comment: Yes. I can see the plugin directory mounted to the pod.
```
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  plugins:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
```